# Is the set of unitary matrices compact in finite dimensions?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

I am trying to show that the set of unitary matrices is compact in finite dimensions.

I began by expressing a non-invertible matrix as a sequence of invertible matrices and then breaking these matrices down into their polar decomposition i.e. $A_n = U_nP_n$.

Next, i need to show if $U_n$ has a limit?

Any hints to point me in the right direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is closed because it's the inverse image of $I$ under the continuous mapping $A \mapsto AA^{*}$.

The set is bounded because each entry of a unitary matrix has modulus $\leq 1$.

Comment: thanks this really helps. Don't suppose you know how to show that it is closed using a sequence/subsequence with a limit?

Comment: If $A_n \to A$, then $A_n A_n^{*} \to AA^{*}$.

Comment: Hmm.. don't really understand! From this:

Comment: $A_nA_n^* = (U_nP_n)(U_nP_n)^* = U_nP_nP_n^*U_n = I$ - something to do with this?

Comment: Sorry, my $A_n$ represented a unitary matrix.

Comment: Okay - so why is that true then??

Comment: What is your definition of a unitary matrix?

Comment: A matrix U is unitary if $UU^* = I = U^*U$

Comment: Clearly, one of those two equalities is enough, say $UU^{*} = I$. Assume you have a sequence $U_n$ of unitary matrices, and $U_n$ converges to $U$. Since $U_n$ is unitary, we have $U_n U_n^{*} = I$. This implies $UU^{*} = I$. Therefore $U$ is unitary.

Comment: Okay i get it now! thanks so much for your patience and help!